# NoSuchProvider JavaX Mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I always get the Error:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Invalid protocol: null
    at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:620)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:600)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:586)
    at de.jankrb.mailcrawler.methods.CheckAll.check(CheckAll.java:23)
    at de.jankrb.mailcrawler.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:10)
```

I didn't try anything, because I didn't find anything on the internet.

This is making trouble:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
            properties.put("mail.user", USER);
            properties.put("mail.password", PASS);

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect(HOST, USER, PASS);
```

Launcher.java:10 just uses the method, where the snippet above is inside.

Comment: Every solution I found didnt worked at all.

Comment: How have you built and configured your application?  What JavaMail jar file are you using?

Comment: @BillShannon I'm using the default Java JVM Template of IntelliJ (JetBrains), JDK 8 and downloaded the latest version on the JavaMail website

Comment: I don't know what the "default Java JVM Template of IntelliJ" is.  Is it repackaging the JavaMail class files inside the jar file or your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", HOST);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "true");
        //properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
        store.connect(HOST, USER, PASS);

        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

This is the code i'm using and its working. Thanks anyways

Comment: you had a mistake in your configuration. It should be `properties.put("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "true");` ?

Comment: Oh sure, I'll edit my answer, in my code its right.